How to match the size of InteractiveGraph with tkinter window?
I'm working on some code using python netgraph. I've got it to work with tkinter, so the window is visible inside tkinter, but I wanted it to match the size of the tkinter window. 
I've tried scaling and modifying the figure and axis, but they still don't really match. I want the black border to match the size of the tkinter window.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.patch.set_edgecolor('black')
ax.patch.set_linewidth(1)
ax.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)
plot_instance = InteractiveGraph(
    g, node_size=5, node_color=node_color,
    node_labels=True, node_label_offset=0.1, node_label_fontdict=dict(size=20),
    edge_color=edge_color, edge_width=1, ax=ax, scale=(2, 2))



Those are just the figure borders of the matplotlib window.
You can remove them with figure.subplots_adjust:
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)


Hi, so I got the scenario with two nodes, but still, it looks like this. The top-bottom is stretched out.
link to photo

You are autoscaling the view, so the axis only covers the extent of the artists. As the axis width-to-height ratio does not match the figure width-to-height ratio, there has to be a border around the axis to make up for the difference. Ensure that the figure and the axis have the same aspect: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8)); ..., ax.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
